# Scala - pattern matching traits that have "self type" as type argument gives unchecked warning

Tags: scala, generics, immutability, traits, generic-programming

I'm trying to define "immutable setter traits", and generic functions for those.

I have a working implementation, but i'm bit disturbed about the "unchecked" warnings from the pattern matching. I'm not really sure what i can do about it.

```
type Point = (Double, Double)

trait Sizable[A] {
  this: A =>
  def size: Point

  /* immutable object value setter, returns a new of the same object*/
  def size(point: Point): A with Sizable[A]
}

def partitionToSizable[T](elements: List[T]): 
  (List[T], List[T with Sizable[T]]) =
    elements.foldLeft((List[T](), List[T with Sizable[T]]()))((p, c) =>
      c match {
        case a: T with Sizable[T] => (p._1, p._2 ++ List(a))
        case a => (p._1 ++ List(a), p._2)
      })
```

The code above demonstrates the problem.

I'm not even sure how big of an issue is that T being unchecked, since all the elements in the list will have a type of T, and the point of the pattern matching is not to determine if it's type is T since we already know that.

In theory Sizable will always have type of T because of the signature of it's enclosing function.

If it's there is no other solution i'd at least like to suppress the warning. @unchecked annotations does not seem to suppress the warning.

If i modify case a: T with Sizable[T] to case a: Sizable[_] it will not compile, since the result type will obviously not confirm to T.

ClassTags or TypeTags might solve the warning, but i suspect they are not necessary really. (also that might have a performance overhead and TypeTags don't work with Scala.js)

Comment: Why do you need such a sophisticated definition of Sizeable? It resembles me the single linked list definition.

Comment: @AntonDanilov what do you mean? It's not a list, it provides a common, generic interface of creating a new immutable instance with one property change. Also, it's not about Sizable, this is just an example for the concept. If you know any better method for doing that, i'd take that as an answer.

Comment: Are you aware of case class copy? It is a more general and powerful alternative to what I think `Sizeable` is meant to be.

Comment: @Simon i'm aware of copy, it's used in one of the example. 

The problem is that copy is not a generic concept, and it only available in the concrete case class.

As the example shows, Sizable is not a sealed trait , so it has an unknown number of implementation, so i can not resolve the final classes in pattern matching. Even if i could that would be a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: @Simon If you know a better solution i'm happy to hear that. i can't image how would a case class copy be an alternative here.

Answer (score 1):

I think just `case a: Sizable[T @unchecked] => a.size((15,20))` should work.

Comment: That in itself does not solve the problem, since then i would need to cast the result of this block to T, so it would be like `a.size((15,20)).asInstanceOf[T]`. I'd like to avoid using asInstanceOf. Also it does not answer the more pressing question, is there a better solution, or if it's really a problem that it's unchecked.

Comment: Why would you need to cast? `Sizable[T].size(Point)` returns `T`.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, the Scala compiler does
`Error:(125, 20) type mismatch;
 found   : Positionable[T] with Material with Sizable[T @unchecked]
 required: T`

Comment: You are right, i have omitted some part of the code, that's why it works here. I update the question's example with the part that causes the problem.

Comment: In this case Yawar's answer is correct: this partition doesn't make sense. Unless you also have some subtypes of `T` which extend `Sizable[T]` and some which don't?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is in `partitionToSizable`. It's taking a `List[T]` and then trying to partition it into a `List[T]` *and* a `List[T with Sizable[T]]`. You are taking a list of a single type and then saying that one type `T` is actually two different types `T` and `T with Sizable[T]`. This indicates an issue with your type design. I would recommend solving that first.

One solution might be to recognise that things that are sizable and things that are not sizable should be represented as two different types. Then you can use the following signature:

```
def partitionToSizable[T1, T2 <: Sizable[T2]](
  elements: List[Either[T1, T2]]): (List[T1], List[T2])
```

Then you don't need to cast; you can pattern match or fold on the `Either`.

Comment: I wanted to simplify my question, but now it might be lacking. What you are suggesting would still need a partition method, since it'd keep T (and subtypes of T) in one List. It's impossible to separate them, since there are other similar traits like Positionable, Colorable, etc... and their combinations. These are graphical elements, where in some cases order might matter. With a mutable approach it's much easier, since you don't need to return anything, and you could just match to `case a:Sizable`. The type design may not be the best, but i don't have better ideas, while keeping it generic.

Comment: @MátéMagyar yeah, I think I'm missing what you're trying to achieve with this partitioning. Usually with graphical elements I would not be throwing them together into a single bucket and then later trying to separate them; I'd be keeping them very separate.

Comment: I'm not sure how to keep them separated, since right now there are 120 possible combinations of the traits that are used now(and i think there will be more, it's a factorial figure, so if i add one more it shoots up to 720), so that would obviously not work.     One thing that might work are HLists, but that would also required polymorphic functions to work with them and it would raise the complexity significantly.    The goal is that i have a function that will organize elements, and resize elements that can be resized if necessary (to fill / fit into specified constraints) and to be generic.

Comment: @MátéMagyar then you might be better off with an Entity Component System design. Your graphical elements, the entities, become just ID numbers in an array and their behaviours, Sizable/Positionable/Colorable, become key-value pairs in separate maps.

Comment: The problem with that is that it would mean i'm losing runtime safety.

Comment: @MátéMagyar yes, to an extent. You would basically need to handle possibly-missing components (behaviours) at runtime. But given the understanding that I haven't seen large parts of the problem, that's the best I can offer 

Comment: The problem is that run time management requires synchronization, which kill multi threading (also possible run time errors).  There is no point in writing swing or javaFx with slight alterations. I'm trying to make it safe and concurrent, and in the end it's not just for graphics components. But thanks anyway for trying to help.